# How to change opencv version from 3.2 to 2.4 in windows?

Tags: opencv

I was using opencv 3.2. Now i want to switch to 2.4. I have extracted the opencv package from the msi installer for windows. Now how to i change the version of opencv in python?

I am using IDLE for my project.

Comment: it is all about what are you linking....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツwhen i am using cv2.__version__ to check it shows 3.2. How to i link the libraries of 2.4 to it